# Поочередная смена классов

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как правильно реализовать схему смены классов.

1. *motionGoingAnim* - хранилище классов.
2. *enemy* - объект, на который навешиваются классы.

При таком коде все классы навешиваются на элемент, а нужно сделать замену на следующий. То есть, поочередно, начиная от 0 до *motionGoingAnim.lenght* (icon1 => icon2 => icon3 => icon1 => icon2 ...) При этом предыдущий класс нужно удалить.
*icon* это модель персонажа в *svg*. В *css* заданы *background-image*. Если есть какой-то лучший способ буду признателен.

```
var motionGoingAnim = ['icon_01','icon_02','icon_03']; 
if (numberAnim === motionGoingAnim.length) {
    numberAnim = 0;
} else {
    enemy.addClass(motionGoingAnim[numberAnim]);
    numberAnim++;
}
```

Comment: `enemy.removeClass(motionGoingAnim[numberAnim-1]).addClass(motionGoingAnim[numberAnim]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вараинт:

```js
var enemy = $('#enemy');
var motionGoingAnim = ['icon_01', 'icon_02', 'icon_03'];
var numberAnim = 0;

changeIcon();

function changeIcon() {
  if (numberAnim == motionGoingAnim.length) {
    enemy.removeClass(motionGoingAnim[numberAnim - 1]).addClass(motionGoingAnim[0]);
    numberAnim = 0;
  } else {
    enemy.removeClass(motionGoingAnim[numberAnim - 1]).addClass(motionGoingAnim[numberAnim]);
  }

  numberAnim++;

  setTimeout(changeIcon, 1000);
}
```

```css
#enemy {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: background 0.7s ease;
}
.icon_01 {
  background-color: red;
}
.icon_02 {
  background-color: green;
}
.icon_03 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="enemy"></div>
```

**UPD.** Добавил transition.

Comment: повезло, `что removeClass(undefined)` ничего не делает, а не падает

Comment: спасибо. removeClass(undefined) я думал упадет, надо было проверить. Это то что надо. Еще раз спасибо большое

Comment: А вообще какой способ более правильный для svg анимации? Я постараюсь сам разобраться. С растровыми изображениями можно с background position, а как быть с вектором?

Comment: @Grundy, в jQuery частенько случается так, что код пытается удалить классы, которых у элемента нет, например, когда нужно удалить класс у некоторых элементов коллекции, не зная у каких именно. Поэтому не посчитал необходимым делать ещё один if, чтобы обрабатывать такой вариант.

Comment: @HelpaMnePlz, если вы не будете делать анимацию `path`, то svg ничем не отличается от png. Для плавности анимации можно добавить `transition`. Добавил его в пример.